# Finding the Variance-Covariance matrix of IRLS output

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, variance, covariance, h2o

How can I obtain the Variance-Covariance matrix of estimated coefficients, $\hat{\beta}$, which are a result of some GLM (solved for example using IRLS. Is there a reference you can direct me to?

In R the function is `vcov` however, it does not detail the computation. Bonus points, if there is an easy way to obtain it using H20.

Comment: Are you asking how to obtain it in R? That sounds more like a programming question

Comment: No. I understand how to use the function in R, i'm asking on the details of the implementation (how to obtain it).

Comment: Although the GLM might be *solved* with IRLS, that's merely a particular algorithm to find the maximum likelihood solution -- and the Fisher Information Matrix supplies the estimate.  So, refer to any account of maximum likelihood theory.